# Android 6.0 HTTPClient issue with LG G3 phone

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apache-httpclient-4.x, android-6.0-marshmallow

Hi I am using DefaultHTTPClient class to create http request.

The currrent code execute() method works on all phones including Nexus and Samsung with Android 6.0.

But when i tested on LG phones with Android 6.0 update, i am getting error as shown below

```
 Java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
03-28 17:21:17.040: E/xx_SDK(14035):  at org.apache.http.impl.auth.DigestScheme.isGbaScheme(DigestScheme.java:210)
03-28 17:21:17.040: E/xx_SDK(14035):  at org.apache.http.impl.auth.DigestScheme.processChallenge(DigestScheme.java:176)
03-28 17:21:17.040: E/xx_SDK(14035):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.processChallenges(DefaultRequestDirector.java:1097)
03-28 17:21:17.040: E/xx_SDK(14035):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.handleResponse(DefaultRequestDirector.java:980)
03-28 17:21:17.040: E/xx_SDK(14035):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:490)
03-28 17:21:17.040: E/xx_SDK(14035):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
03-28 17:21:17.040: E/xx_SDK(14035):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492)
03-28 17:21:17.040: E/xx_SDK(14035):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:470)
03-28 17:21:17.040: E/xx_SDK(14035):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I tried to understand what issue, It talks about Digest authentication.

I know from Android 6.0 they have removed Apache Http client and now uses HTTPUrlConnection class

I tried to copy the *"org.apache.http.legacy.jar"* file from sdk to my project lib folder.

But still i face the same error log. I hope someone can help me to get wor around with this issue.

Kindly find the application code as it is :

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
ClientConnectionManager connectionManager = null;
try {
KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
trustStore.load(null, null);
SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);     
registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));
connectionManager = new SingleClientConnManager(params, registry);
}
catch (Exception e)
 {
  Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
 }

 ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, mTimeOut);
 HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, mTimeOut);
 HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, mTimeOut);
 HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(params, true);

 DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(connectionManager, params);

client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(host,port),
new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userID,passowrd));

client.setRedirectHandler(new RedirectHandler() {
@Override
public boolean isRedirectRequested(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) {
}
@Override
public URI getLocationURI(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) throws ProtocolException {
}

try {
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget);  // issue occur here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ran into something similar and had a fix I'm trying that I added to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35708938/apache-http-client-android-exception-on-execute-only-for-lg-g3-6-0)

---

I ran into a similar issue today and just started using [HttpClient for Android](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html)

1. Added dependency `compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'` to build.gradle.
2. Replace `new DefaultHttpClient()` with `HttpClientBuilder.create().build()`

There are probably some other minor refactors you might need to make in other portions of the code, but that should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: I used the library as per the Android 6.0 specification. useLibrary "org.apache.http.legacy.jar" .  What i see is that it sends the http request. the server responds with 401 code and we send again with Digest authentication. If you see the error log, i feel some issue with the Digest paramaters.  Meanwhile can you tell me how to use ur new code. I cannot understand how to change the DefaultClient. Your second point is not clear

Comment: I was also using the legacy jar, but was still getting the error *only on LG G5 and LG G3*. I don't see sample code, so I'm assuming you have some place where you are using the `DefaultHttpClient` from the apache library. If you add the new dependency, then you need to update the code where you are using the `DefaultHttpClient` to use the `HttpClientBuilder` before making the request. This will use the new code in `httpclient-android` and should handle the digest parameters correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments. I am really happy to see your support. This is a very critical issue for me.  As per your comment, i have updated my app code . Now you can see the code above. KIndly support me on how to change this code as per the HttpClientBuilder.

Comment: I was able to rectify the lg phone error using the answer you had given me and the library mentioned. Everything works fine , until i saw that HTTPS connection is not working. I am not able to make the app work when using HTTPS. Hence i have added a new question for it.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677494/ssl-https-connection-gives-error-when-using-httpclient-for-android.   Kindly help me to rectify the ssl issue using the new library

Answer (score 0):

Give something like this a go, i had similar problem on MotoX running 6.0.1 but this seem to work for me.

```
 protected static final int HTTP_JSON_TIMEOUT_CONNECTION = 20000;
 protected static final int HTTP_JSON_TIMEOUT_SOCKET = 20000;

 CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
   try {
        UserPrefs.clearCacheFolder(mContext.getCacheDir());
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = getApacheHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = getHttpPost( invocation);

       response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    protected CloseableHttpClient getApacheHttpClient(){
    try {
        // Socket config
        SocketConfig socketConfig = SocketConfig.custom()
                .setSoTimeout(HTTP_JSON_TIMEOUT_SOCKET)
                .build();
        // Auth
        CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(URL, PORT, null, "Digest"),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(USERNAME,DIGEST_PASSWORD));
        // Build HttpClient
        return HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultSocketConfig(socketConfig)
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                .build();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("ApacheHttpClientHelper", "ERROR >> "+e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Also stick this into the gradle under dependencies

```
  compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
```